# Can't access external Kandao Ooocom camera via USB

Tags: 18.04, usb, webcam

I have a Kandao Qoocom camera and I can stream with it with Windows and Mac, but I wanted to connect to Ubuntu and the camera is not recognized.

Using `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:56a6 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 2aad:6503  
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:07f8 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 600 (model 1576)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can see that the camera is the device 029 which has an empty description

And with `usb-devices` I get:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=04 Dev#= 29 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2aad ProdID=6503 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=KanDao
S:  Product=KanDao QooCam
S:  SerialNumber=01.00.00
C:  #Ifs= 6 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
```

Is there any way I can mount this USB so I can access the camera?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that the camera is UVC-compliant, you should be able to use `guvcview`.

You can install `guvcview` with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

Comment: I had tried that but instead of gucview I used skype but both of them only recognize the integrated camera.